# URL redirect in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating php system using codeigniter framework. I'm using basic framework without any templates. When I submit data from html page to controller to save to db after redirecting with the error message to view file, i can't remove the url that i used to save data in controller file. How I solve this problem?

This is the form i used to send data to controller.

```
<form role="form" action="save_user_type" method="POST" >
<div class="row">

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label>User Type</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="type" id="type" placeholder="Enter ...">
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6"></div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn default">Save</button> <button type="button" class="btn default">Reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

This is the controller function i called.

```
function save_user_type(){
    try {
        $this->load->model('Configuration/Configuration_model');
        if($this->Configuration_model->save_types() == 1){
            $success['done'] = "Good Job";
        }else{
            $success['dont'] = "Error";
        }
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('template/menubar');
        $this->load->view('configuration/user/index',$success);

    } catch(Exception $exc){
             return $exc->getTraceAsString();
         }
}
```

Please Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: use it . redirect('redirect/computer_graphics');

Answer (score 0):

You will need to redirect to a new controller/function in order to get the URL to change in the browser. I'm going to call the controller `control` and add a couple functions to handle success and failure.

```
public function save_user_type(){
    try {
        $this->load->model('Configuration/Configuration_model');
        if($this->Configuration_model->save_types() == 1){
            redirect('control/save_success');
        }else{
            redirect('control/save_fail');
        }
    } catch(Exception $exc){
         return $exc->getTraceAsString();
      }
}

public function save_sucess(){
   $this->load->view('template/header');
   $this->load->view('template/menubar');
   $this->load->view('configuration/user/index');
}

public function save_fail(){
   $this->load->view('template/header');
   $this->load->view('template/menubar');
   //the "fail" view will have the error message 
   //and maybe a link back to the page with the form.
   $this->load->view('configuration/user/fail');
}
```

Another option for presenting a failed attempt is to use sessions to pass an error message back to the controller/function that loads the form and redirect to that page instead of the `save_fail` page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to redirect to your index page after submitting your data.
You may please use this instead of loading view page.

```
redirect('controller_name/function_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

use flashdata to show messages and redirect to another page.

```
function save_user_type(){
    try {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('Configuration/Configuration_model');
        if($this->Configuration_model->save_types() == 1){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success',"Good Job");
            redirect('controller_name/function_name');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error',"Error Occured");
            redirect('controller_name/function_name');
        }
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('template/menubar');
        $this->load->view('configuration/user/index',$success);

    } catch(Exception $exc){
             return $exc->getTraceAsString();
         }
}
```

On view to show message use `$this->session->flashdata('success');` for success and `$this->session->flashdata('error');` for error

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but Address bar doesn't get to the right path. I want to redirect function in same file. But url appeared wrongly.

Comment: what you tried and what you are getting wrong please shoe me

Comment: I want to make submit form and send success message to view file. i create it but url of address bar doesnt change. it's remaining function that i used to save data to db. i want to direct that page to initial controller function

Comment: i create it using flashdata. but when i used new action in same controller it doen't get the correct path. it only get function name

Comment: what you have written to redirect page? Please show here.